# Mysql group by won't use index after 1 million rows

Tags: mysql

I want to run some query on my MySql innodb table like this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(quantity* price1) AS price1sum,
    SUM(quantity* price2) AS price2sum,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantitysum
FROM
   mytable
WHERE
   date between '2015.01.01' AND '2015.03.18'
GROUP BY id
```

The result is the following (all good)

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  mytable   range date            date    3       922060  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

My problem is if I increase the range of the date the query won't run, the explain gives the following response.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(quantity* price1) AS price1sum,
    SUM(quantity* price2) AS price2sum,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantitysum  
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    date between '2015.01.01' AND '2015.03.19'
GROUP BY id
```

The result is (bad)

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  mytable   index date             id    4        5563915 Using where
```

If I force it to use index with FORCE INDEX (date) it will work but why won't it use index by default?

I tried to tweak the config file of the mysql service but I did now found any reference to this issue.

**EDIT:**

show createtable output:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`primary` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`quantity` double(10,3) NOT NULL,
`price1` double(12,4) NOT NULL,
`price2` double(12,4) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`primary`),
KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `date` (`date`),
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5470283 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT2:**

I noticed mysql starts not to use index after 1 million rows

Comment: Will it be faster, if you use `FORCE INDEX (date)`? MySQL has to decide, which index to use - `date` for `WHERE` or `id` for `GROUP BY` (sorting). For the second query MySQL "thinks" `id` would be the better index to use. Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`.

Comment: well in the secod query if i wont use FORCE INDEX (date) the query won't even run, it will timeout after some minutes.

Comment: Please provide more details like table size, result size, runtime and table structure, if you want to get a good answer.

Comment: Try the composite index on (date, id). If it helps, you can remove the date index.

Comment: already tried, it helped me to increase the between range by 10 days but after that same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing more memory to the server and to the process solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do search without between operator. Because as I know the between operator not use date indexes. Rewrite your query like this and retry again (on my case It is not working, but on some mysql versions it will work):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(quantity* price1) AS price1sum,
    SUM(quantity* price2) AS price2sum,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantitysum
FROM
   mytable
WHERE
   date >= '2015.01.01' AND date <= '2015.03.18'
GROUP BY id
```

I think this problem is a mysql optimizer bug. On large range optimizer decides it is better to chech all table than use indexes. You can see here a bug report about this problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58190

Comment: same result but i noticed mysql wont use index after 1 million row

Comment: Yes it is probably a mysql optimizer bug as I above wrote. If you go to the link that I put you'll see a bug report about this problem. I hope they will fix it on new versions of mysql. But now you have to use force index unfortunately

Comment: it won't work with between i understand it but why wont it work with

date >= '2015.01.01' AND date <= '2015.03.18'

the above two query has the completaly same issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be you indexed the date field twice? Please check it.
Can you write here the result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable" query? I'd like to look at your table, indexes and types